# Backbone.js binding dynamic el generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a small problem where I am creating a view and dynamically creating the "el" element and passing it on to the view that I am creating.

```
var divIdentification = ".data-identification-"+this.model.dataTypeId+"-"+this.model.dataGrouping.get("data1Id")+"-"+this.model.dataGrouping.get("data2Id");
```

THE FOLLOWING WORKS

```
var roomOccupancyView = new Bookings.RoomOccupancyView({
                    model: datas,
                    el: "div"
                });
```

HOWEVER THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT

```
var divIdentification = ".data-identification-"+this.model.dataTypeId+"-"+this.model.dataGrouping.get("data1Id")+"-"+this.model.dataGrouping.get("data2Id");

    var roomOccupancyView = new Bookings.RoomOccupancyView({
                        model: datas,
                        el: divIdentification 
                    });
```

When I try placing a console.log for el in the child view for the first scenario where I pass el as a string I get the following object

```
<div class="header-container">
```

HOWEVER when I pass the variable I get "undefined".

Additionally I also tried wrapping the variable output as $(string) however that too did not work as the console.log still provides a different output.

Does anyone have any idea to pass a dynamic value into the el attribute value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
MilindaD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the comment, the `el` attribute passed in through initializer function can only be a `String` or jQuery object. Otherwise, Backbone will create an el from it's `tagName`, `className` and `id` attribute.

So in your first scenario, you passed `el: "div"` and Backbone will then bind the view's `el` to the first `div` element in the DOM.

In your second scenario, you passed `el: divIdentification` and Backbone will set view's el to $(divIdentification) which is not defined in your DOM.

In order for you to set `el` dynamically. 3 methods

1. assign value of `el` in the initializer a valid html string, or selector string or just a valid jQuery DOM object.
2. assign `className` or `id` attributes to divIdentification in the initializer to allow Backbone view to create its own `el`
3. Another method is to use `setElement` [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement)

Comment: I figured you'd be back to clarify things so I gave you a pre-emptive upvote before.

Comment: @coderek `As pointed out by the comment, the el attribute passed in through initializer function can only be a String or jQuery object` this statement is false, because Backbone create the `el` like this `this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'), false);` and from this http://underscorejs.org/#result the el can be a function, I have already tested somthing like this `el : function() {return "someEl"}` and it worked.

Comment: Agreed. I should rephrase it as "can only be something that evaluates to a String or jQuery object"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is where your create your `divIdentification` the keyword `this` in not pointing o your view, try this :

```
var roomOccupancyView = new Bookings.RoomOccupancyView({
                    model: datas,
                    el: function() {
                    return ".data-identification-" + 
                        this.model.dataTypeId + 
                        "-" + this.model.dataGrouping.get("data1Id") +
                        "-"+this.model.dataGrouping.get("data2Id");
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: nope, the same problem.... the console.log is giving a string whereas when I pass "div" or something directly to "el" I am getting a object or something (I am not too sure) pointing to the div element